# MSBuild doesn't utilize project.lock.json

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

I'm trying to build project with references in project.json on my build agent.
I installed on it "Microsoft Build Tools 2015 Update 3" from https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-build-tools but still MSBuild doesn't find references from project.json file.

On my local machine were I installed Visual Studio Update 3 everything works, but I don't want to install it on build agent

Comment: I'd look at: 1) Installing the server-side .net core package. 2) Making sure you use MSBuild from Program Files, not from C:\windows. 3) Making sure you .csproj and not .xproj.

Comment: @MikhailOrlov - ad 1) I'm not using .NET core. Rest is done